# Why select_related in Django ORM apply join before where clause?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework

Consider I have two tables namely

```
Class Department(model.Models):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

Class Employee(model.Models):
   dep = models.ForeignKey(Department)
   exp = models.IntegerField()
```

Now in views class I am using get_queryset function

```
def get_queryset(self):
  return Employee.objects.using(schema).filter(exp_gte=date).select_related('dep')
```

Sql statement create is in this form

```
Select `Employee`.`dep`, `Employee`.`exp`, `Department`.`id` from `Employee` 
Inner Join `Department` on `Department`.`id`= `Employee`.`dep` 
Where `Employee`.`exp` >= date;
```

Why is join before where clause. And how can I apply join after where clause using Django ORM

Comment: That is correct SQL.... You seem to be mistaken here. A where clause before the join won't be valid SQL (and also doesn't make sense)

Comment: I want to create a subquery in which I want to apply where clause before join operation. How can I achieve this in django orm?

Comment: Something like this

Select * from (Select * from `employee` where `employee`.`exp` >= date) as emp
inner join `Department` as d on emp.dep = d.id;

Comment: What's the benefit here? The results would be the same. Your database would in fact work more efficiently without the subquery.

Comment: The benefit would be I will only apply join on those employee which have experience greater than a certain date. Instead of joining the whole table. If ihave a millions of rows in employee table the join cost would be huge. But if I am able to get only a hundred of rows the join cost would be significantly less.

Comment: If I am wrong correct me please

Comment: Are you sure it would work better? Have you tested it by running both queries? Checked the Query plans? Even though I am not experienced with databases I feel that a Join would work better.